# When are static variables handy for session management in a servlet?

Tags: java, variables, static

When are `static` variables handy for session management in a `servlet`?

I have looked arround for this answer but most of the answers I found describe mainly when and why not to use `static` variables

so I would like to know it what cases would it be preferable or not a bad idea to use `static` variables.

Comment: _when and why not_ versus _preferable or not a bad idea_. Seems like you already have your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should never use static variables for session management, unless you're using a singleton pattern, since you have objects that you want accessible based on a session, but not inside of the session.  This might be a case for example when doing session replication.  However, these are edge cases, and you should stay away from them unless you have a really good reason.